How to animate shape keys using python scripting?
I am new to Blender and Blender scripting, and I want to animate a character model's facial expressions using Python. I have read that shapekeys can be used to set various mouth poses, but I’m unsure how to animate these shapekeys through scripting.
Could anyone guide me on how to approach this or point me to any resources that explain how to animate shapekeys with Python in Blender?
Thank you!

What do you mean by "how to animate shapekeys with Python"? Relative shape keys can be applied to the basic shape by specifying a value between 0 and 1.  So, you are just looking for a script that sets this value? There are also absolute shape keys but I guess you are using relative shape keys for the facial expressions, don't you?

Do you want to drive your shape keys via python on every frame, like from some capture device? There are drivers that you write in python. And also application handlers.

Give an example of a rig or a character you are trying to animate and what is the animation information you want to apply with python.

Yeah.... question is too vague....

So, assuming that you have shapekeys created (good basic tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i519chZ-esU ), all you need is to set keyframes with different "value" for each shape key.
In a python script, you can set keyframes for the value of each shape key as in this small example:
import random
import bpy

#getting all my shape keys - see below how to find them
key1 = bpy.data.shape_keys["Key"].key_blocks["Wiggle_R"]
key2 = bpy.data.shape_keys["Key"].key_blocks["Wiggle_L"]
key3 = bpy.data.shape_keys["Key.001"].key_blocks["Stretch"]


#creating a random animation
for frame in range(1, 200, 40):
    
    #set the value for each shape key
    key1.value = random.random()
    key2.value = random.random()
    key3.value = random.random()
    
    #add keyframes for each shape key
    key1.keyframe_insert(data_path="value", frame=frame)
    key2.keyframe_insert(data_path="value", frame=frame)
    key3.keyframe_insert(data_path="value", frame=frame)

To find the path of each shape key, go to the data tab of your object, select one of the shape keys, right click the "value" and "copy full data path".
Notice that this code only adds keyframes, so, if you want to change the animation, you should delete the existing keyframes first.
To set some other properties of the created keyframes, you can access them in bpy.data.actions[actionName].fcurves[curveIndex].keyframe_points, where actionName is like "KeyAction" and "Key.001Action", although these names change if it's not the first time they're created. You can see the names in the dopesheet by selecting some row and pressing N for properties.
